# Trouble opening the gallery on android 2.2

Tags: android, android-intent, gallery, image

I have made two buttons. One that opens the camera and one that opens the gallery. The camera one works fine but the gallery one does not… It opens but when I choose a picture from the gallery the application closes unexpectedly.

```
package com.example.me;

import android.os.Bundle;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{


Button b;
ImageView iv;
Intent i;
final static int cameraData = 0;
Bitmap bmp;
private static final int SELECT_IMAGE = 1;
Button clickk;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    initialize();
    InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
}


private void initialize() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    iv = (ImageView) findViewById (R.id.imageView1);
    b = (Button) findViewById (R.id.btakePic);
    clickk = (Button) findViewById (R.id.bChose);
    b.setOnClickListener(this);
    clickk.setOnClickListener(this);
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()){

    case R.id.btakePic:
        i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(i, cameraData);
        break;
    case R.id.bChose:
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);//
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select  Picture"),SELECT_IMAGE);
    }
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        bmp = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    }

}
}
```

Here are logs:

```
08-05 11:30:19.455: E/ActivityThread(5576): Activity           com.android.internal.app.ChooserActivity has leaked IntentReceiver   com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity$1@412fd3e0 that was originally registered here.  Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
08-05 11:30:19.455: E/ActivityThread(5576): android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity com.android.internal.app.ChooserActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity$1@412fd3e0 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
08-05 11:30:19.455: E/ActivityThread(5576):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:763)
08-05 11:30:19.455: E/ActivityThread(5576):     at android.app.LoadedApk.getReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:567)
08-05 11:30:19.455: E/ActivityThread(5576):     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1099)
08-05 11:30:19.455: E/ActivityThread(5576):     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1086)
08-05 11:30:19.455: E/ActivityThread(5576):     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1080)
08-05 11:30:19.455: E/ActivityThread(5576):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:348)
08-05 11:30:19.455: E/ActivityThread(5576):     at com.android.internal.content.PackageMonitor.register(PackageMonitor.java:65)
08-05 11:30:19.455: E/ActivityThread(5576):     at    com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity.onCreate(ResolverActivity.java:101)
08-05 11:30:19.455: E/ActivityThread(5576):     at    com.android.internal.app.ChooserActivity.onCreate(ChooserActivity.java:53)
08-05 11:30:19.455: E/ActivityThread(5576):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
08-05 11:30:19.455: E/ActivityThread(5576):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1053)
08-05 11:30:19.455: E/ActivityThread(5576):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1934)
08-05 11:30:19.455: E/ActivityThread(5576):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995)
08-05 11:30:19.455: E/ActivityThread(5576):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:128)
08-05 11:30:19.455: E/ActivityThread(5576):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161)
08-05 11:30:19.455: E/ActivityThread(5576):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-05 11:30:19.455: E/ActivityThread(5576):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-05 11:30:19.455: E/ActivityThread(5576):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)
08-05 11:30:19.455: E/ActivityThread(5576):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-05 11:30:19.455: E/ActivityThread(5576):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-05 11:30:19.455: E/ActivityThread(5576):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
08-05 11:30:19.455: E/ActivityThread(5576):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
08-05 11:30:19.455: E/ActivityThread(5576):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-05 11:30:19.471: D/OpenGLRenderer(5576): Flushing caches (mode 1)
08-05 11:30:42.932: D/AndroidRuntime(5576): Shutting down VM
08-05 11:30:42.932: W/dalvikvm(5576): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception   (group=0x40be41f8)
08-05 11:30:42.932: E/AndroidRuntime(5576): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-05 11:30:42.932: E/AndroidRuntime(5576): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://media/external/images/media/774 }} to activity {com.example.me/com.example.me.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
 08-05 11:30:42.932: E/AndroidRuntime(5576):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2994)
08-05 11:30:42.932: E/AndroidRuntime(5576):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3037)
08-05 11:30:42.932: E/AndroidRuntime(5576):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:128)
08-05 11:30:42.932: E/AndroidRuntime(5576):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1191)
08-05 11:30:42.932: E/AndroidRuntime(5576):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 08-05 11:30:42.932: E/AndroidRuntime(5576):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 08-05 11:30:42.932: E/AndroidRuntime(5576):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)
 08-05 11:30:42.932: E/AndroidRuntime(5576):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  08-05 11:30:42.932: E/AndroidRuntime(5576):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
  08-05 11:30:42.932: E/AndroidRuntime(5576):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
 08-05 11:30:42.932: E/AndroidRuntime(5576):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
 08-05 11:30:42.932: E/AndroidRuntime(5576):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
  08-05 11:30:42.932: E/AndroidRuntime(5576): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 08-05 11:30:42.932: E/AndroidRuntime(5576):    at com.example.me.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:72)
 08-05 11:30:42.932: E/AndroidRuntime(5576):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:4649)
 08-05 11:30:42.932: E/AndroidRuntime(5576):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2990)
 08-05 11:30:42.932: E/AndroidRuntime(5576):    ... 11 more
```

Here is what I have now. It still does not work. I'm guessing I'm supposed to put something between the camera result and the gallery result?

```
     @Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
     if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
         Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
         bmp = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
         iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);
         if (requestCode == SELECT_IMAGE) {
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){  
                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,   filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();
                Log.i(myTag, filePath); 
                File imgFile = new File(filePath);
                //Get your image out of the file
                //do with it what you will.
                Bundle extras1 = data.getExtras();
                bmp = (Bitmap) extras1.get("data");
                iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Also is the my tag supposed to be a string?

```
  @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == cameraData)
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)   {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        bmp = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);



        if (requestCode == SELECT_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView)   findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
               imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to handle the gallery differently than the camera in your onActivityResult(). Here is a rough example of what you'll need to do to handle the choose image from gallery case.

```
if (requestCode == SELECT_IMAGE) {
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){  
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();
        Log.i(myTag, filePath); 
        File imgFile = new File(filePath);
        //Get your image out of the file
        //do with it what you will.
    }
}
```

Comment: would i need to change anything under the case R.id.bChoose:   ?

Comment: i am getting an error on the mytag when i retype the Log.i(string tag , string msg) what tag am i suppose to put in there? a list of string services come up and i looked on the android developer site to see what they are but i dont see any that would relate to the gallery http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#WINDOW_SERVICE

Comment: replace `myTag` with any string that you want. Ideally it will be something unique to your app so that you can filter based on it in the eclipse logcat window. i.e. `"GALLERY EXAMPLE"`

Comment: ok good i understand that.. now it says local variable imgFile not found.  i dont know what to name this variable like Button b; i put in File imgFile; and it does nothing

Comment: [Check out this tutorial](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/pick-image-from-galary-android-app/) for a good overview of how to implement it.

Comment: ok thank you this worked but only if i delete the camera part of the onActivityResult out. is it because of                                            Bundle extras = d    ata.getExtras();
   bmp = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
   iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);

Comment: The bmp factory has two different ways to move the images and the one above is the camera one...so im pretty sure thats the problem.  am i suppose to put something like "if not this then this"?

Comment: yeah, you can use `requestCode != SELECT_IMAGE` to get a camera branch in your if statement. You'll also still want to check `resultCode == RESULT_OK` in that branch also.

Comment: i have a request code but when i put a ! point in front of the = it does not work at all here ill put in my new code

Comment: i cant use a switch there seems to be an error with { } brackets and no matter what i do i always get an error...like deleting or adding them

Comment: ok i found the problem!!! there was a braket that was below the gallery method that was suppose to be for the camera method i will post the results and your code helped me the most thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try this code....

```
 yourGalleryButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                                 photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
                                startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, 1);
            }
        });

     protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultcode, Intent intent)
      {
          super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultcode, intent);


          if (requestCode == 1)
          {
              if (intent != null && resultcode == RESULT_OK)
              {             

                    Uri selectedImage = intent.getData();

                    String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                    cursor.moveToFirst();
                    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                    String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                    cursor.close();

                    if(bmp != null && !bmp.isRecycled())
                    {
                        bmp = null;               
                    }

                    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);


              }
              else
              {
                  Log.d("Status:", "Photopicker canceled");           
              }
          }
      }
    }
```

This is easy and simple code.....

Comment: Please explain your code: what changed, what is the fix. Don't throw code without any explanation nor comment

Comment: the code that changed is insted of using the bundle extras to transfer the picture for the gallery i used the image view one.  the code you posted still does not work it brings me to a gallery and everything but when i pick a picture it goes back to my app but doesnt display the picture i choosed

Comment: Set above Bitmap("bmp") in your imageview.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that worked. i will put ------- by the bracket that i moved to make the activity work. there were 3 brakets below and i just moved one up.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);



    if (requestCode == cameraData)
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)   {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        bmp = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    -----}


        if (requestCode == SELECT_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));


            }



    }
```